# How to search user input Names from database.Example abc@mail.com. It should search the abc@mail.com in db and give me abc's details

Tags: php, database, email

```
//where "candi_s_by_mail" is my field id, "cand_mail" is my db column and $cand_mail is varibale where i have stored field user input data. 

if(isset($_POST['candi_s_by_mail']))
{
  $sql="SELECT  * FROM candidate WHERE cand_mail=$candmail";
  echo "Selected candidate mail details";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());; 
echo "in result";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
  $FirstName  =$row['cand_fname']; 
  $LastName=$row['cand_lname']; 
  $Mail=$row['cand_mail'];  
}
```

I want to query my search as when a user inputs chars or text it should display only that

Comment: Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: what is $candmail in your code?

Comment: @Jens..We have a search text box. If user inputs for example- abc@mail.com. It should search abc@mail.com in database and display the details of ABC like its name..contact..adddress etc.

Comment: @satishrajak..$candmail=$_POST['candi_s_by_mail']; -its a vaiable where we have stored text field values. I am new to PHP.

Comment: @Roshan the correct your query $sql="SELECT  * FROM candidate WHERE cand_mail='$candmail'"; text should be written in quotes

Comment: @satishrajak..Thank you Satish. I was trying since 2 days. Thank again .It worked for me.

Comment: @satishrajak make an answer with your comment ;)

Comment: Now we have to search for multiple text field. Example:- Designation,Location,Qualification,Gender,Experience etc. we some some including textfields like gender and Location. as well excluding qualification field.so output should be only including textfield keyword. and avoid excluded keywords.

Comment: @satishrajak we have commented satish above. thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per our discussion $_POST['candi_s_by_mail'] is a text so we need to write query like this

```
SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cand_mail='$candmail';
```

string or text should be written in quote.

Comment: Satish, have you recommended a SQL injection vulnerability to @Roshan?

Comment: @halfer...I have one the code for sql injection.  But how we can have Anding & Or-ing query for multiple textfields. How can we achieve sql injection for such long queries.